# Emulator Log is not getting

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-logcat

I run the application form eclipse in the emulator. But am not getting the log.
The emulator is created form eclipse.

Device :  Nexus 5
Target : Android N

When i try to run am getting error in console

```
An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

I stop the android studio and every thing , but still the log is not getting from the emulator

Comment: I want the log in eclipse, not in android studio. Also create the emulator from eclipse avd.  @Sathish Kumar J

Comment: then restart your eclipse

Comment: i tried, but still no log